# Not able to properly delete the rows in excel using office interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

//I am trying to delete some of the rows in excel. But the problem i am facing is that its not deleting all the  records, its deleting some rows and leaving behind the remaining rows.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)           
{              
    Array MyValues = (Array)MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "AN" + i.ToString()).Cells.Value;

    if (Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 1)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 2)) == "" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1, 3)) == "")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Excel.Range cells = MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "AN" + i.ToString());
        cells.Delete();                      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looping backwards solves my question.

```
i.e for(i=lastrow;i>=2;i--)
     {
       //delete
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are using break instead of continue in your if statement?

Also, You must be careful when combining a loop with deletion. Lets say your loop deletes row 5, now row 6 will become row 5 and the loop will skip it. This might be whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are deleting by iteration.

so you delete, for example, the first row but then the cells move upwards. So your "i" is now at 2 and you skipped the first row that was move up.

FIX:

cells = MySheet.get_Range("Ax", "ANx");

"x" is where ever you want to delete the row from